# Android In-app Billing condition?

Tags: android, conditional-statements, in-app-billing

I wanted to know how do I create a condition (eg. If the user buys an item can show a specific activity if not, no.) So how can i write, checking to see if a user has purchased the item. Do you think the code can work for items that you can buy only once?

I followed a guide for writing it. This is my code.

```
public class Acquisti_In_App extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "com.Amarildo.Acquisti_In_App";
    IabHelper mHelper;

    static final String PRINCIPIANTE_SKU = "com.amarildo.raccolta_principiante";
    static final String INTERMEDIO_SKU = "com.amarildo.raccolta_intermedio";
    static final String AVANZATO_SKU = "com.amarildo.raccolta_avanzato";

    private Button principiante, intermedio, avanzato;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.acquisti_in_app);

        principiante = (Button)findViewById(R.id.principiante);
        intermedio = (Button)findViewById(R.id.intermedio);
        avanzato = (Button)findViewById(R.id.avanzato);


        String base64EncodedPublicKey =
                "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAwPC4dwcGb33Hp+823BtSe909sXNIHHkmzLOJCynHWh73P4BJZmsRm5oESGBcpwQTrak3hpthOtyJI4deSbg6N67nRjV9aJ3jXWAhOD//CLQvTZDtBHy9V4B+G5BhXNxd6BscNfa0iullCzbKyDuPou+o66dTItM0TFJAGEHiizdToY7peJrtLN5X4P+wRCzGiL3Awan7ZEj26y+U0lDQbWzCTKacIbr+K4giazaRvT217FnKuvVUIeqf0eiy+SqYsdYEQFy0XT6wmICO3LsoOSgPNyu8Nlezp3tqiMMjSae14hu7YFnBXxtrn9fHeaAlx/osnEs79VDNMYybFdJYOwIDAQAB";

        mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

        mHelper.startSetup(new
                                   IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
                                       public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result)
                                       {
                                           if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                                               Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing setup failed: " +
                                                       result);
                                           } else {
                                               Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing is set up OK");
                                           }
                                       }
                                   });
    }

    public void principiante(View view) {
        mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, PRINCIPIANTE_SKU, 10001, mPurchaseFinishedListener, "principiante");
    }

    public void intermedio(View view) {
        mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, INTERMEDIO_SKU, 10002, mPurchaseFinishedListener, "intermedio");
    }

    public void avanzato(View view) {
        mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, AVANZATO_SKU, 10003, mPurchaseFinishedListener, "avanzato");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode,
                resultCode, data)) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener
            = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result,
                                          Purchase purchase)
        {
            if (result.isFailure()) {
                // Handle error
                return;
            }
            else if (purchase.getSku().equals(PRINCIPIANTE_SKU)) {
                consumeItem();
            }
            else if (purchase.getSku().equals(INTERMEDIO_SKU)) {
                consumeItem();
            }
            else if (purchase.getSku().equals(AVANZATO_SKU)) {
                consumeItem();
            }

        }
    };

    public void consumeItem() {
        mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mReceivedInventoryListener);
    }

    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mReceivedInventoryListener
            = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
                                             Inventory inventory) {

            if (result.isFailure()) {
                //trattere errore
            } else {
                mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(PRINCIPIANTE_SKU),mConsumeFinishedListener);
                mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(INTERMEDIO_SKU),mConsumeFinishedListener);
                mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(AVANZATO_SKU),mConsumeFinishedListener);
            }
        }
    };

    IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener =
            new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
                public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase,
                                              IabResult result) {

                    if (result.isSuccess()) {
                        //clickButton.setEnabled(true);
                    } else {
                        // handle error
                    }
                }
            };

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mHelper != null) mHelper.dispose();
        mHelper = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the user starts the app or after the purchase was concluded, you should check the purchases made by that user by calling the method `getPurchases` through your *ServiceConnection*:

`Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", null);`

If you are working with consumable items then you should consume them with the method `consumePurchase`:

`int response = mService.consumePurchase(3, getPackageName(), token);`

As stated in the [Android Developers page](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#QueryPurchases):

> The Google Play service returns only the purchases made by the user
>   account that is currently logged in to the device. If the request is
>   successful, the returned Bundle has a response code of 0. The response
>   Bundle also contains a list of the product IDs, a list of the order
>   details for each purchase, and the signatures for each purchase.

When you get the purchases you can check which item the user bought and present the activities/fragments that correspond to their purchases. From the example code in the page:

```
int response = ownedItems.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
if (response == 0) {
   ArrayList<String> ownedSkus =
      ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST");
   ArrayList<String>  purchaseDataList =
      ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST");
   ArrayList<String>  signatureList =
      ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE");
   String continuationToken = 
      ownedItems.getString("INAPP_CONTINUATION_TOKEN");

   for (int i = 0; i < purchaseDataList.size(); ++i) {
      String purchaseData = purchaseDataList.get(i);
      String signature = signatureList.get(i);
      String sku = ownedSkus.get(i);

      // do something with this purchase information
      // e.g. display the updated list of products owned by user
   } 

   // if continuationToken != null, call getPurchases again 
   // and pass in the token to retrieve more items
}
```

Like this you can specify what Activities or Fragments should be displayed to the user.

Also I would recommend for you to place your token for the In-App Billing process in a different file, just a security measure.